# In addition to def, is there any way to define functions in python?

Tags: python, lambda

are there other ways to define functions in python? These are my current writing methods

```py
def create(first):
    def runner(second):
        print(first, second)
    return runner
```

```
obj = {}
def a():
    'a'
def b():
    'b'
def c():
    'c'
obj['a'] = a
obj['b'] = b
obj['c'] = c
```

I know lambda, but it seems to only support single line. Is there a way to do something like the following:

```py
def create(first):
    return xxx(second):
        return print(first, second)
```

```py
obj = {
    'a': xxx():
        'a'
    'b': xxx():
        'b'
    'c': xxx():
        'c'
}
```

Or is there a more beautiful way of writing?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Using [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is the usual way of attaching several functions to an object in Python

Comment: i think you can add `__call__` but it's ugly